# Haskell filtering a nested list with specific data constructors

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Suppose I have the data type

```
data Joke = Funny String | Lame String
```

and say I have the following nested list

```
[[Funny "Haha", Lame "boo"], [Funny "Haha"], [Lame "BOO"]]
```

How would I go about filtering such a nested list so that any list within the nested list that contains `Funny "Haha"` is removed? In other words, I'm trying to filter the list so that I receive the following result:

```
[[Lame "BOO"]]
```

Any list that contains `Funny "Haha"` is removed.

Would appreciate any help, I'm having a terrible time learning Haskell and how to do things with lists and custom data types.

Answer (score 4):

As a preliminary step, let's derive `Eq` and `Show` instances for your type:

```
data Joke = Funny String | Lame String
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

`Eq` makes it possible to test the (in)equality of `Joke`s, while `Show` makes it possible to display the results of your tests in GHCi.

[`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) is the right tool here:

```
excludeHaha :: [[Joke]] -> [[Joke]]
excludeHaha = filter (notElem (Funny "Haha"))
```

This filters the (outer) list so that only inner lists with all elements different from `Funny "Haha"` are kept.

Trying it out:

```
GHCi> excludeHaha [[Funny "Haha", Lame "boo"], [Funny "Haha"], [Lame "BOO"]]
[[Lame "BOO"]]
```

If you don't want to hardcode `"Haha"`, add a parameter and pass it on to the test:

```
excludeAFunnyJoke :: String -> [[Joke]] -> [[Joke]]
excludeAFunnyJoke s = filter (notElem (Funny s))
```

```
GHCi> excludeAFunnyJoke "LOL" [[Funny "LOL", Lame "boo"], [Funny "Haha"], [Lame "BOO"]]
[[Funny "Haha"],[Lame "BOO"]]
```

If you wanted instead to exclude all `Funny` jokes, regardless of what the contained `String` is, you could use pattern matching to define an appropriate test:

```
excludeFunny :: [[Joke]] -> [[Joke]]
excludeFunny = filter (all (not . isFunny))
    where
    isFunny :: Joke -> Bool
    isFunny joke = case joke of
        Funny _ -> True
        _ -> False
```

The filtering test here uses [`all`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any), which applies its own test (here, `(/= Funny "Haha")`) to the elements of the (inner) list and then folds the resulting `[Bool]` with `(&&)`.

(You might as well define `isLame` and use it instead of `not . isFunny` -- note, though, that that would only work because you happen to have just two constructors.)

```
GHCi> excludeFunny [[Funny "LOL", Lame "boo"], [Funny "Haha"], [Lame "BOO"]]
[[Lame "BOO"]]
```

---

P.S.: A manual implementation of the `Eq` instance would look like this:

```
instance Eq Joke where
    Funny x == Funny y = x == y
    Lame x == Lame y = x == y
    Funny _ == Lame _ = False
    Lame _ == Funny _ = False
```

You might replace the last two cases by a catch-all (`_ == _ = False`), saving one line at the cost of making it a little easier to forget updating the instance if you ever add more constructors to `Joke`. In any case, such definitions are boring busywork, so we avoid it with `deriving` unless there is a need for a non-obvious equality test.

Comment: How would I do it without deriving Eq? Also, for the pattern matching, you wrote the function excludeHaha = filter (all (/= Funny "Haha")). But, you hardcoded the value "Haha", how would I do it for the general case? For example, if the String said "X", the function would destroy all the lists that are Funny "X". Or if the String was "Y", the function would destroy all lists that had Funny "Y".

Comment: @Lol I added that to the answer as well.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is: Given a nested list, check the first list, and then check the first element. If it is Funny, then remove all lists in the nested list that contain Funny x, and return the updated nested list. But the problem is the user is inputting only [[Joke]], so I'm never explicitly given a string s.

Comment: @Lol I'm not sure what you mean with the last part -- do you know in advance the string you would give to `excludeAFunnyJoke`?

Comment: a string x*****

Comment: No, I'm only given a [[Joke]] so I have to determine what the string is. So, user inputs [[Funny "lol", Lame "lol"], [Funny "hi", Lame "yes"]] and only that. So I have to check the first list, and see if the joke is Funny. If it is, then remove all lists with Funny "lol" in it - the string is "lol" but I don't know this, I have to find out somehow.

Comment: @Lol One way is using pattern matching on the `[[Joke]]` to get hold of the first element of the first list (just don't forget to handle all cases, including the empty list ones!), and then call `excludeAFunnyJoke` in the appropriate case.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I tried to use pattern matching but it didn't compile when I used the filter command you provided. I edited my post above, can you please take a look?

Comment: @Lol Could you please move the "Part 2" you just added, together with the explanation of your requirements in these comments, to a new question? It gets confusing to other readers (and answerers) if multiple questions are rolled into one.

Comment: @duploade Sure, I created a new thread. Really appreciate your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739861/haskell-filtering-a-nested-list-with-data-constructors