# Haskell filtering data constructor in nested lists

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have the following custom data type:

```
data Particle = Foo String | Goo String
```

with the following call:

```
func [[Foo "a"], [Goo "b", Foo "a"], [Goo "a"], [Foo "d"]]
```

The function definition is:

```
func :: [[Particle]] -> [[Particle]]
```

I want to filter the Nested list of Particle so that my output is the following:

```
[[], [Goo "b"], [Foo "d"]]
```

**To explain in words what func is doing, it takes a look at the first Particle in the first list, which is determined to be Foo "a". It removes Foo "a" from all the lists, and if it happens to find a Goo "a" in any list (including the first one), it completely destroys the list that contains it.**

But my output appears to be wrong. I'm getting

```
[[Goo "a"], [Foo "d"]]
```

when I should be getting

```
[[], [Goo "b"], [Foo "d"]]
```

**(this is because Foo "a" is deleted from the first and second list, Goo "a" destroys the third list, and the fourth list remains unchanged, see the list below)**

*Copy of the list for readability*

```
    [[Foo "a"], [Goo "b", Foo "a"], [Goo "a"], [Foo "d"]]
```

Any help? I know filter and elem are required (I've been playing around with them, but can't get the right ordering), but I can't seem to implement this correctly.

EDIT: Resolved. I had to invest more time into list comprehension. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be asking repeated, minor variations of the same problem (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739022/haskell-filtering-a-nested-list-with-specific-data-constructors and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739861/haskell-filtering-a-nested-list-with-data-constructors).   Some earlier comments ("I cannot change this definition or work around it in any way") suggest that this is a homework assignment.  What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a great case for a list comprehension, in this case a nested one.

```
data Particle = Foo String | Goo String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

func :: [[Particle]] -> [[Particle]]
func []        = []
func xss@(x:_) = [[y | y <- ys, y /= badParticle] | ys <- xss, worseParticle `notElem` ys]
  where
  (badParticle: _) = x
  worseParticle    = case badParticle of
                     Foo s -> Goo s
                     Goo s -> undefined  -- what do you do in this case?
```

Let me break down the comprehension, `where` clause first.

```
(badParticle: _) = x
-- this is equivalent to `badParticle = head x`

worseParticle    = case badParticle of
                   Foo s -> Goo s
                   Goo s -> undefined
-- Just some case matching to go Foo -> Goo
```

then the list comprehension itself.

```
[ [y | y <- ys, y /= badParticle]
  {- a list of every y from ys, where y is not the bad particle
     this is equivalent to `filter (/= badParticle) ys` -}
  | ys <- xss
  {- where ys draws from xss -}
  , worseParticle `notElem` ys
  {- and worseParticle is not an element of ys -}
]
```

---

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/RichSlategrayCommand)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. Thanks for the help again, your explanation really helped!